# MATLAB how to change default compiler?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am working with MATLAB R2015b and trying to use MEX files. When I type the commad line "mex - setup", MATLAB returns me "MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1(C)' for C language compilation". However, to change this default compiler to work with Microsoft Visual Studio Community. 
How can I change the default compiler of MATLAB?

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider accepting it as valid.

Answer (score 2):

`mex -setup` lets you choose the compiler over the **installed** **supported** compilers you have.

Obviously the compiler needs to be installed , and needs to be one of the following : https://uk.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015b/index.html .

"Microsoft Visual Studio Community" does not appear to be on the list.